# Assign dynamically deserialized value to dynamically created instance

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

At runtime, I find the type of an object from which I want to create an instance:

```
string typeName = "myNamespace.type, assembly";
Type theType = Type.GetType(typeName);
// the type features a constructor w/o arguments:
object theInstance = Acivator.CreateInstance(theType);
```

This works fine and in the debugger I can see all attribute values -- I do assume the debugger uses reflection?

I also have a dynamically deserialized object of type object, for which I know that it in fact of type theType:

```
// pseudo code on the rhs of the "="
object deserialized = decoder.decode(serializedObject.body);
```

Is there a way to assign `deserialized`to `theInstance`, without looping over the attributes of the type using reflection? Since this will be time critical: assuming the only way to do this is reflection, is there a way to minimize the performance penalty? I do expect many of these objects in short time.

(This is .Net 3.5, so if Type dynamic could solve this it is of no use in this case).

Comment: Sounds like job for generics

Comment: Why do you need to create an instance of the object before deserializing another?  Why can't you just use the deserialized object instead of copying its attributes onto another object?

Comment: I think this would be downcasting, and that is not allowed in C#. Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @KaiHartmann Downcasting is allowed in C#, it's just an explicit conversion (that can fail with InvalidCastException).

Comment: Ok, thanks. But in this case it would fail, because object 'deserialized' has never been upcasted from the derived class.

Comment: @KaiHartmann No, that's wrong too.  Whether or not a downcast will succeed depends not on the type of the reference but on the type of the object.  If `decoder.decode()` returns an instance of class `A` then one can cast `(A)deserialized` without error, regardless of the fact that `deserialized` is typed as `object`.

Comment: Then your question to Thomas is pretty much valid. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to write a method that copies the attributes from one object of this type to another:

```
static void CopyAttributesOnto(theType dest, theType source)
{
    dest.a = source.a;
    dest.b = source.b;
    // ...
}

// Then you can just do this:
CopyAttributesOnto((theType)theInstance, (theType)deserialized);
```

Another option would be to build a `DynamicMethod` at runtime and create a delegate from it.  You will pay once for the cost of reflection and JIT compilation of the new method, but every invocation of the method will have no more overhead than the use of any other delegate.